# Filtering the site as a non-D&D player

Tags: support, tags

I enjoy using this site from time to time, but  I've got a few very popular tags ignore-listed because I *usually* don't want to read or answer questions about them. (This isn't a value judgement about the game or anything — it's just pointless to look at the majority of D&D5 questions if you're not playing D&D5 and don't have the books on hand to research answers, due to the *highly detail-oriented and game-specific* nature of questions like "How does this spell work?" or "How can I play this kind of character effectively?")

But all the ignore list does is make the text kinda greyish in the main page "Top Questions" view, while most of the content I see is still ignore-listed items. (I don't know exactly how it changed or when, but I remember the grey-out effect being more pronounced in the past as well?)

If I try to set up a custom filter such as "not dnd-5e," I get a popup that says:

> Tag queries cannot be exclusively negative.

What should I do if I actually want to *ignore* the tag categories on my ignore list, so I can focus on less popular game questions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Click edit on the Ignored tags box and swap your setting to Hide, as opposed to Gray out.

[image: image of ignored tags box in edit mode, with free hand circle pointing at the "Hide question" option]

Comment: :O :O :O :O AMAZING, thank you

Comment: [Hiding all the D&D tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Qvl.png) was quite the experience when I tried it.

Comment: @Laurel You need to refresh the page after you change that setting, otherwise it hides the filtered questions but doesn't go back further to buffer up more non-D&D questions.

Comment: @AlexP No, that's not how it works. I tested it again and refreshing does nothing. You get X number of questions and then it removes the ones that you ignore. When I set the page size to 50, there were 5 questions on page 2.

Comment: If i load the page with "gray out" set and then switch to "hide," I see 7 questions on the front page. When I refresh the page, it now displays about 50 questions.

Comment: @AlexP I'm talking about [/questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions). It's the only way to view newest questions, see heavily downvoted questions (less than -3), or use filters.

Comment: @Laurel Ah, I see! Yeah, it's pretty funny/bleak how I only see 3 questions on a page there.